# How to cut text on finding documents in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var PostModel = mongoose.model('PostModel', {
    text : {type : String, default: ''},
    created_at : Date
});
```

`text` field could be long (around 1000 characters). When I query posts on my posts list page I need to query All posts with cut `text` field to 150 characters only.

Which is the best approach to do it? Is it possible to make the cut by using mongoose itself or should I cut text after it retrieving by using `PostModel.find() in success callback`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use virtuals for this. From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do
>   not get persisted to MongoDB. The getters are useful for formatting or
>   combining fields.

In your case, you could use it like this:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : {type : String, default: ''},
    created_at : Date
});

PostSchema.virtual('truncated_text').get(function() {
  return this.text.substring(0, 150);
});

var PostModel = mongoose.model('PostModel', PostSchema);
```

Then you can use `Post#truncated_text` instead of `Post#text`, for example:

```
Post.findOne({}, function(err, post) {
    console.log(post.truncated_text);
});
```

The virtual field will not be saved to the database and will be updated every time you update the `text` field.

Comment: It's too bad that `virtuals` does't support `.lean()` and `.aggregate()` :(

Comment: The point of virtuals is to have a way to create customized fields that are used by your application but shouldn't be persisted to the database. If you want to query or aggregate using that field, you can use the regular `text` field and then use the virtual only when displaying the results.

Comment: I little don't understand what you mean. Could you provide small peice of code?